# Flutter Socket.listen() receives incomplete data

Tags: dart, flutter

Using a socket to receive string data. And it seems like the transmission is incomplete. The server sends around 80 KB and the flutter socket receives sometimes 1 KB and sometimes around 10 KB.

Tried the onDone() handler and it's the same. It's called before the whole data is received.

I also tried breaking the data into multiple pieces. And I get the first and the last packet, but lose everything between.

Is this broken? Here is my code:

```
Future<String> getNetworkData() async {
  String rawData;
  await Socket.connect(ipAddr, port).then((Socket socket) {
    socket.add(utf8.encode(request));
    socket.listen((var data) {
      rawData = utf8.decode(data);
    });

  return rawData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous function that you are passing to `listen` is going to be called multiple times with chunks of the response. It's up to *you* to concatenate them. As you need a string you can use the stream `join` convenience function.

```
Future<String> getNetworkData() async {
  Socket s = await Socket.connect(ipAddr, port);
  s.add(utf8.encode(request));
  String result = await s.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  await s.close(); // probably need to close the socket
  return result;
}
```

This assumes that the server will close the socket when it's finished sending. If you want to reuse the socket then you need to agree a scheme with the server so that you know when it has finished sending. It could tell you at the beginning the length, or you could parse the data as it arrives. This is the same for anyone reading from a tcp socket - regardless of language.

Aside - any time you see `await` and `then` on the same line, be suspicious. It can probably be simplified.