# dart fails when try casting to double

Tags: dart

I have next:

Dart:

```
static sendQuery({required String query,args, dimension}) async {
if(args != null)
  args.forEach((element) => query = query.replaceFirst("?", element));

String ip = shared.getData("remote_ip");
int port = shared.getData("remote_port");
String data =  "";
await Socket.connect(ip, port,timeout: Duration(seconds: 5)).then((soket) {
  soket.write(query);
  soket.listen((Uint8List buffer) async {
    String _buffer = String.fromCharCodes(buffer);
    data += _buffer;
  },
  onDone: () {});
});

print("Data has returned. Length of data: ${data.length}");
return data;}
```

When try do **double.parse(_buffer)**, it fails on **Invalid double**

what do I do wrong?

Edit:

I have a small test for that, I have printed it in bytes.

**List bytes1 = utf8.encode(_buffer);**

**List bytes1 = utf8.encode("90");**

I see a huge diffrence:

**bytes2:** [57, 48]

**bytes1:** [57, 48, 0, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 0, 67, 111, 110, 110, 101, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 99, 108, 111, 115, 101, 100, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 27, 3, 59, 72, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 36, 195, 175, 195, 191, 195, 191, 124, 0, 0, 0, 100, 195, 176, 195, 191, 195, 191, 194, 164, 0, 0, 0, 116, 195, 176, 195, 191, 195, 191, 194, 188, 0, 0, 0, 194, 164, 195, 177, 195, 191, 195, 191, 100, 0, 0, 0, 194, 141, 195, 178, 195, 191, 195, 191, 195, 148, 0, 0, 0, 194, 166, 195, 178, 195, 191, 195, 191, 195, 180, 0, 0, 0, 68, 195, 181, 195, 191, 195, 191, 20, 1, 0, 0, 194, 180, 195, 181, 195, 191, 195, 191, 92, 1, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 122, 82, 0, 1, 120, 16, 1, 27, 12, 7, 8, 194, 144, 1, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 56, 195, 177, 195, 191, 195, 191, 47, 0, 0, 0, 0, 68, 7, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 0, 0, 52, 0, 0, 0, 194, 160, 195, 174, 195, 191, 195, 191, 64, 1, 0, 0, 0, 14, 16, 70, 14, 24, 74, 15, 11, 119, 8, 194, 128, 0, 63, 26, 58, 42, 51, 36, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 92, 0, 0, 0, 194, 184, 195, 175, 195, 191, 19

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Socket.listen() receives incomplete data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020084/flutter-socket-listen-receives-incomplete-data)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the bytes in `buffer`, it starts with the correct `57, 48`. It's then followed by other bytes which spell out things like "close" and "Connection closed", and then some bytes that do not appear to be text.

So the buffer is *too long*. You should stop reading at the first `\0` byte.
Consider trying:

```dart
var end = buffer.indexOf(0);
if (end < 0) end = buffer.length;
buffer = Uint8List.view(buffer.buffer, 0, end);
```

at the start of the `listen` callback.

I'm not sure *why* this happens. Are the bytes actually sent by the other end, or is it a bug in the socket code? Depends on what your server does.

Comment: thanks I will try it.  server sends a simple string, for that scenario server sent string "90"